# Android AutoCompleteTextView, prevent all behaviours onItemClick

Tags: android, search, autocompletetextview

I have checkboxes inside each item on the dropdown suggestion from the AutoCompleteTextView.
Now i want to prevent the suggestion onItemClick?

So Preventing of suggestion in the textview field and also preventing the suggested dropdown list to be removed.

thanks!

Comment: what *exactly* do you want to do?

Comment: you question is confusing would be better if you put any screenshot or code.